# Recurring warning - unable to clean up lease on KCL 2.3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I performed a re-sharding from 1 shard to 2 in my kinesis stream, after which my KCL consumer keeps logging the following warning every one minute.

Unable to clean up lease shardId-000000000006 for newStream due to LeaseCleanupManager.LeaseCleanupResult(cleanedUpCompletedLease=false, cleanedUpGarbageLease=false, wereChildShardsPresent=true, wasResourceNotFound=false)

shardId-000000000006 is the parent shard that was split into two child shards 7 and 8. My DynamoDB entries are like so:

[image]

A restart of the consumer does not help. Is this a cause for concern, and why is the worker unable to clean up the lease on shardId-000000000006?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the expected behavior. Once both the child shards performed the checkpointing, shardId-000000000006 lease was cleaned up without any issues.